# Xamarin app crashing during apple review process

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a Xamarin navigation app for a local walking route, the app seems to work fine on any physical device I try it on, also distribution using the Testflight system seems fine. The android version is available on the app store and works.

However when I submit the IOS app for review, the app always seems to crash when the Apple employee presses the "Get started" button in my app.

Pressing get started switches the app to the gps navigation page and starts the navigation, which is why I'm asuming something goes wrong here: [MapPage.xaml.cs](https://github.com/jelknab/FamilieWandelPad/blob/master/FamilieWandelPad/FamilieWandelPad/Pages/MapPage.xaml.cs)

I have tried different linker settings, because I think that might be the issue, sadly I can not try to disable the linker entirely, because it makes the size of the executable exceed the app store limit.

The project is public: https://github.com/jelknab/FamilieWandelPad

Attached is a symbolicated crash log:

```
{"app_name":"FamilieWandelPad.iOS","timestamp":"2020-08-10 08:53:31.00 -0700","app_version":"0.14","slice_uuid":"e437ebf3-5228-3f83-a108-2c7f00b4b448","adam_id":1514972762,"build_version":"1.0","bundleID":"net.metzlar.FamilieWandelpadKaag","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 13.6 (17G68)","incident_id":"C77FD17E-9438-41F0-A783-2636FB288B00","name":"FamilieWandelPad.iOS"}
Incident Identifier: C77FD17E-9438-41F0-A783-2636FB288B00
CrashReporter Key:   36c14055bb17c6d0db3f456869338332b769d45e
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             FamilieWandelPad.iOS [828]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/A1901BEC-027C-4052-94C1-4EB07B10BE24/FamilieWandelPad.iOS.app/FamilieWandelPad.iOS
Identifier:          net.metzlar.FamilieWandelpadKaag
Version:             1.0 (0.14)
AppStoreTools:       11E707
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [2]
Coalition:           net.metzlar.FamilieWandelpadKaag [761]


Date/Time:           2020-08-10 08:53:31.2876 -0700
Launch Time:         2020-08-10 08:53:21.4905 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.6 (17G68)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    n/a
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  tid_507  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019776cd88 0x197747000 + 155016
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001976851e8 0x197683000 + 8680
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001975d89b0 0x197566000 + 469424
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001975d8940 0x197566000 + 469312
4   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102fc281c xamarin_initialize.cold.1 + 0
5   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102fba000 xamarin_printf + 42655744 (runtime.m:2472)
6   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102ed27a8 mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 41707432 (exception.c:1299)
7   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102e73dbc mono_handle_exception_internal + 41319868 (mini-exceptions.c:2783)
8   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102e74568 mono_resume_unwind + 41321832 (mini-exceptions.c:3532)
9   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102e69c20 mono_arm_resume_unwind + 41278496 (exceptions-arm64.c:421)
10  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000100838768 llvm_resume_unwind_trampoline + 168
11  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x00000001018159fc Xamarin_iOS_UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr + 17865212 (UIApplication.cs:0)
12  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x000000010073f100 FamilieWandelPad_iOS_FamilieWandelPad_iOS_Application_Main_string__ + 56
13  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x000000010080f440 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 272
14  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102e84104 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 41386244 (mini-runtime.c:3165)
15  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f1c444 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 42009668 (object.c:3220)
16  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f2153c mono_runtime_exec_main_checked + 42030396 (object.c:5284)
17  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102e69630 mono_jit_exec + 41276976 (driver.c:1328)
18  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102fc0cc8 xamarin_main + 42683592 (monotouch-main.m:0)
19  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x000000010073d704 main + 202500 (main.m:178)
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001977778f0 0x197776000 + 6384

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197691738 0x197683000 + 59192

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197691738 0x197683000 + 59192

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197691738 0x197683000 + 59192

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197691738 0x197683000 + 59192

Thread 5 name:  SGen worker
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019776cb58 0x197747000 + 154456
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197686ce4 0x197683000 + 15588
2   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f97d20 thread_func + 42515744 (sgen-thread-pool.c:196)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019768dd98 0x197683000 + 44440
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019769174c 0x197683000 + 59212

Thread 6 name:  Finalizer
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019774b1d4 0x197747000 + 16852
1   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102ed494c finalizer_thread + 41716044 (gc.c:965)
2   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f4e418 start_wrapper_internal + 42214424 (threads.c:1288)
3   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f4e29c start_wrapper + 42214044 (threads.c:1309)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019768dd98 0x197683000 + 44440
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019769174c 0x197683000 + 59212

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019774b198 0x197747000 + 16792
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019774a60c 0x197747000 + 13836
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001978f5328 0x19784d000 + 688936
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001978f035c 0x19784d000 + 668508
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001978efba8 0x19784d000 + 666536
5   Foundation                      0x0000000197c4101c 0x197c39000 + 32796
6   Foundation                      0x0000000197c40efc 0x197c39000 + 32508
7   UIKitCore                       0x000000019bace57c 0x19affd000 + 11343228
8   Foundation                      0x0000000197d6fe20 0x197c39000 + 1273376
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019768dd98 0x197683000 + 44440
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019769174c 0x197683000 + 59212

Thread 8 name:  tid_9e03
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019776cb58 0x197747000 + 154456
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197686ce4 0x197683000 + 15588
2   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102fa5d74 mono_os_cond_timedwait + 42573172 (mono-os-mutex.c:75)
3   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102fad1ac mono_thread_info_sleep + 42602924 (mono-threads.c:1672)
4   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f45940 monitor_thread + 42178880 (threadpool-worker-default.c:728)
5   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f4e418 start_wrapper_internal + 42214424 (threads.c:1288)
6   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f4e29c start_wrapper + 42214044 (threads.c:1309)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019768dd98 0x197683000 + 44440
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019769174c 0x197683000 + 59212

Thread 9 name:  Thread Pool Worker
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019774b1ec 0x197747000 + 16876
1   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f4620c worker_thread + 42181132 (threadpool-worker-default.c:490)
2   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f4e418 start_wrapper_internal + 42214424 (threads.c:1288)
3   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f4e29c start_wrapper + 42214044 (threads.c:1309)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019768dd98 0x197683000 + 44440
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019769174c 0x197683000 + 59212

Thread 10 name:  Thread Pool Worker
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019774b1ec 0x197747000 + 16876
1   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f4620c worker_thread + 42181132 (threadpool-worker-default.c:490)
2   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f4e418 start_wrapper_internal + 42214424 (threads.c:1288)
3   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f4e29c start_wrapper + 42214044 (threads.c:1309)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019768dd98 0x197683000 + 44440
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019769174c 0x197683000 + 59212

Thread 11 name:  Thread Pool Worker
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019774b1ec 0x197747000 + 16876
1   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f4620c worker_thread + 42181132 (threadpool-worker-default.c:490)
2   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f4e418 start_wrapper_internal + 42214424 (threads.c:1288)
3   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f4e29c start_wrapper + 42214044 (threads.c:1309)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019768dd98 0x197683000 + 44440
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019769174c 0x197683000 + 59212

Thread 12 name:  Timer-Scheduler
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019776cb58 0x197747000 + 154456
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197686ce4 0x197683000 + 15588
2   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102fa5d9c mono_os_cond_timedwait + 42573212 (mono-os-mutex.c:32)
3   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f55ecc mono_w32handle_timedwait_signal_handle + 42245836 (w32handle.c:767)
4   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f55da4 mono_w32handle_wait_one + 42245540 (w32handle.c:895)
5   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f55fc8 mono_w32handle_wait_multiple + 42246088 (w32handle.c:1002)
6   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f4a49c ves_icall_System_Threading_WaitHandle_Wait_internal + 42198172 (threads.c:2313)
7   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102eea764 ves_icall_System_Threading_WaitHandle_Wait_internal_raw + 41805668 (icall-def.h:1100)
8   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000100758cf8 wrapper_managed_to_native_System_Threading_WaitHandle_Wait_internal_intptr__int_bool_int + 120
9   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000100956cd8 mscorlib_System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOneNative_System_Runtime_InteropServices_SafeHandle_uint_bool_bool + 2403544 (WaitHandle.cs:0)
10  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000100956710 mscorlib_System_Threading_WaitHandle_InternalWaitOne_System_Runtime_InteropServices_SafeHandle_long_bool_bool + 2402064 (waithandle.cs:266)
11  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x00000001009566c0 mscorlib_System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_long_bool + 2401984 (waithandle.cs:0)
12  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x00000001009565a0 mscorlib_System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne_int + 2401696 (waithandle.cs:0)
13  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000100957fd4 mscorlib_System_Threading_Timer_Scheduler_SchedulerThread + 2408404 (Timer.cs:287)
14  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000100951730 mscorlib_System_Threading_ThreadHelper_ThreadStart_Context_object + 2381616 (thread.cs:80)
15  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x000000010094fcc8 mscorlib_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_RunInternal_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 2374856 (executioncontext.cs:969)
16  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x000000010094faec mscorlib_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_Run_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object_bool + 2374380 (executioncontext.cs:911)
17  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x000000010094fa64 mscorlib_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_Run_System_Threading_ExecutionContext_System_Threading_ContextCallback_object + 2374244 (executioncontext.cs:900)
18  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x00000001009518b4 mscorlib_System_Threading_ThreadHelper_ThreadStart + 2382004 (thread.cs:111)
19  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x000000010080f440 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 272
20  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102e84104 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 41386244 (mini-runtime.c:3165)
21  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f1c444 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 42009668 (object.c:3220)
22  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f2106c mono_runtime_delegate_try_invoke + 42029164 (object.c:4437)
23  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f4e510 start_wrapper_internal + 42214672 (threads.c:1257)
24  FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f4e29c start_wrapper + 42214044 (threads.c:1309)
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019768dd98 0x197683000 + 44440
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019769174c 0x197683000 + 59212

Thread 13 name:  Thread Pool Worker
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019774b1ec 0x197747000 + 16876
1   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f4620c worker_thread + 42181132 (threadpool-worker-default.c:490)
2   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f4e418 start_wrapper_internal + 42214424 (threads.c:1288)
3   FamilieWandelPad.iOS            0x0000000102f4e29c start_wrapper + 42214044 (threads.c:1309)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019768dd98 0x197683000 + 44440
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000019769174c 0x197683000 + 59212

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x0000000000000036   x7: 0xffffffffffffffec
    x8: 0x000000010b711840   x9: 0x922ca237905ebebe  x10: 0x00000000000003e8  x11: 0x0000000000bf3d01
   x12: 0x0000000119908000  x13: 0x0000000000004009  x14: 0x0000000119904000  x15: 0x0000000000003fff
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000a2f  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000507  x21: 0x000000016f6f2570  x22: 0x000000010b711920  x23: 0x000000010c81d550
   x24: 0x00000001198fb2c8  x25: 0x000000010d056e68  x26: 0x000000010c80e000  x27: 0x0000000000000003
   x28: 0x000000010080f43f   fp: 0x000000016f6f1780   lr: 0x00000001976851e8
    sp: 0x000000016f6f1760   pc: 0x000000019776cd88 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

Added appcenter bug tracking as per suggestion, this seems to be the problem:

```
{
  "length": 0,
  "offset": 0,
  "id": "32ed9f52-8113-4d5d-914a-17302e3680a6",
  "exception": {
    "type": "Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.GeolocationException",
    "message": "A geolocation error occured: Unauthorized",
    "stackTrace": "  at Plugin.Geolocator.GeolocatorImplementation.GetPositionAsync (System.Nullable`1[T] timeout, System.Nullable`1[T] cancelToken, System.Boolean includeHeading) <0x105434cbc + 0x00a48> in <a535528283564881a0f1e27c648d0f3b#ff4393fe8a06b7a3c4b6d831f1f7e640>:0 \n  at FamilieWandelPad.navigation.Navigator.StartNavigation () <0x1043e3dc0 + 0x003ab> in <7715b699a0204ede8c0f571ecfcdf8e7#ff4393fe8a06b7a3c4b6d831f1f7e640>:0 ",
    "wrapperSdkName": "appcenter.xamarin"
  },
  "properties": {
    "permission status": "False"
  },
  "appId": "87a72e54-a7d2-4e81-bf84-c85239d780b2",
  "installId": "91F4842B-2F6B-4602-B99A-4297B12DA0B6",
  "isTestMessage": false,
  "timestamp": "2020-09-24T11:23:00.277Z",
  "sid": "4db62a61-3233-4ca0-ba96-4fb37256f471",
  "device": {
    "sdkName": "appcenter.ios",
    "sdkVersion": "3.3.3",
    "wrapperSdkVersion": "3.4.1",
    "wrapperSdkName": "appcenter.xamarin",
    "model": "iPad7,3",
    "oemName": "Apple",
    "osName": "iOS",
    "osVersion": "12.3",
    "osBuild": "16F156",
    "locale": "zh-Hans_CN",
    "timeZoneOffset": -420,
    "screenSize": "1668x2224",
    "appVersion": "0.16",
    "appBuild": "1.0",
    "appNamespace": "net.metzlar.FamilieWandelpadKaag",
    "wrapperRuntimeVersion": "12.6.0"
  }
}
```

For some reason the app reaches this point without having location permissions, even through the user should not be able to. Sadly I can not really see what they are doing to achieve this, but none of my testflight users are able to bypass the permissions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: there is no exception handling on that page so any error will cause a crash.  What happens if there is no connectivity or no GPS?  You can also use a tool like appcenter.ms to capture info on crashes in the field.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Jason, the app is a single download and does not communicate any data, the app store review team also mentioned their devices being connected to wifi, just like my test device. The app should just stay stuck on a looking for gps screen if it doesn't find anything, they don't mention getting that screen, just an instant crash after the start button press apparently. I've not heard of appcenter, I will look into this, thank you!

Comment: You can give a alert or a load activityIndicator when  looking for gps so it will not stay stuck.  BTW, did you request the location permission in the info.plist?

Comment: @Jason I've set up the appcenter and added some try-catch statements to the code. It would seem the problem is caused by a permission error: "Plugin.Geolocator.Abstractions.GeolocationException: A geolocation error occured: Unauthorized"

I'm looking into it myself, but I'd like to thank you for your suggestions as it might have saved this project.

Comment: how does your app behave if the user does NOT grant location permissions?

Comment: It will notify the user that location has to be enabled from settings, after pressing ok, the user will be navigated to the Settings app and the app will shut down.

Comment: Have you add the permission in the info.plist?

Comment: Hello Jack, yes I have. My app has finally passed the review stage by me just catching the exception and not doing anything with it, I still see the error coming in from devices apple seems to test with. It is now being beta tested by a large group of locals and none have been able to reproduce the issue and it works just as it should. I don't know what makes the review devices special, but for some reason they always have permission issues.

Comment: If the problem is solved please either answer the question or delete. Don't leave a stale question hanging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue by adding appcenter issue tracking. The problem still persist on apple review devices, but has now passed review by try-catching the issue and not doing anything with it. The app works fine on any other devices.